# Adding numeric value count to fetch array php

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have query which retrieves and then prints rows of data, but what I am trying to is just add a number in the '$rank' column. So for example if there are 10 rows that come up in the query, I want the query to put a 1 in the first row, 2 in the second and so on...

It is not so much a ranking system, I just want a number to appear in the left column that counts each row. The query I posted below just puts a '1' in the column, can anyone help?

```
    <?php 

    $bg = '#ffffff'; // Set the background color.
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        $i=0;
        $rank = $i+1;   

        $bg = ($bg=='#e1e3e6' ? '#cdcdcf' : '#e1e3e6'); // Switch the background color.   
        echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bg . '">';

        echo  '<td align="center">' . $rank . '</td>';
        echo  '<td align="center">' . $row['sales_model'] . '</td>';
        echo  '<td align="center">' . $row['sales_customer_firstname'] . ' ' . $row['sales_customer_surname'] . '</td>';
        echo  '<td align="center">' . $row['sales_vin'] . '</td>';
        echo  '<td align="center">' . $row['sales_rda'] . '</td>';
        echo  '<td align="center">' . $row['sales_commission_no'] . '</td>';
        echo  '<td align="center">' . $row['sales_points'] . '</td>';

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: you dont need $rank and $i, just using $rank starting at 1 (`$rank=1;`) then at the end of the loop  add `$rank++;` before the `}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
     /* while code here */
     ++$i; //increment the counter by 1
}
```

Comment: PS, I replaced $rank with $i